# How can I skip N lines of a QFile without temporarily storing them in QStrings?

Tags: c++, qt, qfile

Basically if I call `QFile::readLine`, the entire line of a `QFile` will be copied and pasted into a `char*` or a `QByteArray`. If I want to skip 999 lines to go straight to the line of interest (the 1,000th one), then I will be copying & pasting the first 999 lines for no reason whereas I just want to skip them.

I know that `istream::ignore` enables the user to skip any number of characters until the delimiter is found, so

```
std::ifstream file("file.txt");

for (auto i = 0u; i < 999u; ++i)
    file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

std::string str;
getline(file, str); // The 1,000th line is copied & pasted into str
```

would make you go straight to the 1,000th line without wasting any time copying and pasting. How can I do the same thing with `QFile`?

Comment: You could call `getChar` in a loop until you see 999 newline characters.

Answer (score 1):

Qt has no API for seeking a file to the next occurrence of a specific byte without outputting the read data.

You can get quite close, though:

`QFile` has `QIODevice::readLine(char *data, qint64 maxSize)`, which reads into a preallocated buffer and could be used like this:

```
QFile f("..."); f.open(...);

int maxSize = 1024; // guess that 1kb will be enough per line
QByteArray lineData(maxSize, '\0');
int skipLines = 100;
while(f.readLine(lineData.data(), maxSize) > 0 && skipLines > 0) {
    --skipLines;
}
```

This call of `readLine()` reuses the preallocated buffer.

You can see that the critical part here is guessing which preallocation size is best. If your line is longer than the guessed size, you will skip less than 100 lines, because each longer line takes several reads.

`QTextStream` uses an internal buffer size of 16kb:

from qtextstream.cpp:

```
static const int QTEXTSTREAM_BUFFERSIZE = 16384;
```

`QIODevice` uses the same buffer size:

from qiodevice_p.h:

```
#define QIODEVICE_BUFFERSIZE Q_INT64_C(16384)
```

---

Sidenote:

`QTextStream` also has `readLineInto(QString *line, qint64 maxlen = 0)` which dynamically reallocates `line` if `maxlen` is 0 or the length of the read line is < `line->capacity()`. But, because of encoding, reading into a `QString` is always slower than reading into a `QByteArray`.

A function like `readLineInto(...)` doesn't exist for `QByteArray`, though.

---

The solution using `QIODevice::getChar(char *c)` (proposed in the OP comments) is suitable, too, because it uses the same internal read buffer as `readLine`, has a bit overhead for each call, but the caller doesn't have to worry about lines longer than the chosen buffer size.